# BST insertion with C++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I created a function to insert data to a BST and it works fine. I used "pass by reference" and the value of "head" is supposed to change after each insertion. However, I found that the "head" is always pointing to the first value that I inserted. Could anyone here explain what causes the "head" to point to the first data I inserted?

```
void insert(node *&head, int val){
if(head == NULL){
    head = newNode(val);
}
else{
    if(val <head->data)
        insert(head->left,val);
    else
        insert(head->right,val);
}
}
```

Comment: I think this is correct that "head' always points to head (root), isn't it what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is how the function should work, `head` should never change or you will lose track of the tree root.

as long as you have the `head` pointing at the root, you have access to the whole tree.

the reason why the value is not changing is, when you are writing `insert(head->left,val);`

you are not assigning a new value to `head`, you are just passing the reference to the left child to the next function call.

Answer (score 0):

```
void insert(node *&head, int val){
if(head == NULL){
    head = newNode(val); // when you call insert() with pointer to root
                         // which is NULL this will create root node
}
```

then when you add data to the root node (whch is not NULL anymore)

```
else{ // this will be called and this doesn't create new root node
      // but just create nodes at its left or right side 
    if(val <head->data)
        insert(head->left,val);
    else
        insert(head->right,val);
}
}
```

Comment: thank you. That makes sense. when the first node is created, head is changed. The following nodes just change head->left, head->right, and etc.